# Can DIIOP support Ltpa token 2 now?

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I ve do some research for a few days.We now have a domino 9.0.1 remote server. With the SSO configurated. It uses ltpa Token2 to utilize SSO. Now I want use DIIOP in java to create a session via NotesFactory class with (server,token) where server is the remote server name and token is acquired through request header(I filter the request with a Filter ofc). with no success:

> Error message: Notes Exception: failed to authenticate Single sign-on token.

I tried another way, I used username and password to create the session s

```
Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(server,username,password)
s.getSessionToken
```

> Error message: Notes Exception: failed to generate Single sign-on token.

first one is very possible to happen but second one is weird.
`createSession` with username and password got no error alone, I tested.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, didn't post a question before thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it seems that DIIOP still didn't support LtpaToken 2
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21989014

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Well I have come across that Q&A before, just want to confirm.